# Access Json object from ajax success function - Unexpected Undefined

Tags: jquery, json

I have following ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/ajax",
        type: "get",
        data: values ,
        success: function (data) {

           console.log(data); // This is Line 7
           console.log(data[0].first_name);  //// This is Line 8      

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }


    });
```

Line 07 Output : `[{"id":2,"first_name":"Nimalka","last_name":"Perera","address":"Kandy","age":25,"created_at":"2017-08-29 07:23:43","updated_at":"2017-08-29 07:23:43"}]`

Line 08 Output : `undefined`

Why is **line 08** undefined?

When I check the output with JSFiddle it works Fine. ( [Link to the JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2yN6/1044/))

But why it is undefined in inside $.ajax function?

Comment: You are getting a string response. First convert it to object using JSON.parse.

Comment: @Shubham Thanks. It worked :-) Even I return as Json in PHP File (`return json_encode($students);` ) why it getting as string?

Comment: javascript is not expecting an Object. You have to set dataType to JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the `data` into JSON then access the key value

```
 success: function (data) {
           console.log(data); 
           var response = JSON.parse(data);
           console.log(response[0].first_name);        

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As your question is **why** I will explain what happens.

As other have mentioned, `typeof data == "string"`. Ths means that `data[0]` will be the first character in your string.

In case of `[{"id":2,"first_name":"Nimalka","last_name":"Perera","address":"Kandy","age":25,"created_at":"2017-08-29 07:23:43","updated_at":"2017-08-29 07:23:43"}]` it will be character `'['`

As such, `data[0].first_name` means that JavaScript will get the value for key `first_name` of Object `'['`, which is not defined, thus returning `undefined`.

Of course, the solution is to **parse the string to json**, as other mentioned.

Comment: I do not think this explanation is relevant here.

Comment: Actually I believe it helps others learn how to debug themselves, so it's **very relevant**

Answer (score 0):

A better and simple thing to do here is, on your Ajax configuration you can set the expected Response type is of JSON. This will force Jquery to parse the data for you.

**Here is the code:**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/ajax",
        type: "get",
        data: values ,
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function (data) {

           console.log(data); // This is Line 7
           console.log(data[0].first_name);  //// This is Line 8      

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }


    });
```